# Second monitor not working

Tags: ubuntu, acer

My Acer monitor which is plugged into my Razer Blade 15 laptop is now not being detected in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS after installing an nvidia driver (sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall) I have no idea if this is how to update drivers. It is not detecting it at all when I go to Settings > Devices > Displays. It still works just fine in Windows 10. Is it as simple as uninstalling? I have tried sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y && sudo apt updatebut still don't have any luck.

Comment: Personally I use `xrandr` (a CLI tool) whenever I need to query or do anything with displays/monitors. In particular, if you just run `xrandr` without any arguments you will get some plain text output that you could post into your Question

Comment: @cryptarch Thank you for your response. I ran `xrandr` and pasted results into Google and [someone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093763/ubuntu-wont-detect-second-monitor-on-hdmi) asked this question. I see they were able to resolve the issue but unfortunately I'm not tech-savvy enough to understand his answer. He deleted all Nvidia files and add ppa repos and installed a later version of the drivers in tty